# What is a more rigorous definition for powers of rational numbers?

Tags: exponentiation, rational-numbers

My current understanding of $x^\frac{m}{n}$ is that it is equal to $\sqrt[n]{x^m}$. Now technically, (-1)$^\frac{2}{4}$ is equal to $\sqrt[4]{(-1)^2}$=1. As $\frac{2}{4}$=$\frac{1}{2}$, (-1)$^\frac{1}{2}$ is technically equal to 1. However, the square root of -1 is i, not 1. How do I resolve this argument? I'm guessing the rule for raising numbers to rational powers applies only to irreducible fractions but is that it, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 2):

Defining $x^{m/n}$ as $\sqrt[n]{x^m}$ is only done when $x\geqslant0$, not for every $x\in\Bbb R$. Otherwise, we will run into trouble, as you have noticed. Actually, we can still define $x^{m/n}$ as $\sqrt[n]{x^m}$ when $x<0$, but only when $n$ is odd.